# Five Finger Pinch Close in UI Automation

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I want know whether five finger pinch gesture can be simulated using UI automation iOS.

The five finger pinch minimizes the app and shows the device home screen.

I know the `pinchCloseFromToForDuration` but it only handles 2 finger pinch gesture.

Comment: I have been searching for this too for a while. I don't think there is a way to do this using Instruments. I guess such type of test is best suited for manual than automation

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved only on devices that have been jailbreaked.

5 finger pinch is a default feature for Apple iPad and cannot be simulated devices that have not been jailbreaked.

However, 2, 3 & 4 finger can be done using `pinchCloseFromToForDuration`.